# SOAPUI default https configuration

Tags: https, mule, soapui, mule-studio

I am trying to connect to an https endpoint by creating a soapui project. I do not have to make any changes in my soapui project to connect on https. Not done any configurations for TLS. Not done any keystore configs. The https request still goes through and returns data.
However, if I try to call the https endpoint from my code (Mulesoft webservice consumer) it tries to find the certificate.

Is there some default configuration for soapui that makes this thing happen ?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "it tries to find the certificate." ?  Is there any error message or warning when doing the handshake?

Comment: Just check the headers that are being passed from soapui by clicking on 'Raw' tab in request. Try passing the same headers from Mule by setting them as properties. (Content-Type, SOAPAction etc)

Comment: @tortoise , Yeah thats what seemed to solve the issue. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I did get a resolution long back but was too busy with project deadlines to update the answer here.
Yes, Some headers that SOAPUI passed along with the request that I was not aware of. When I looked at the raw request it was clear.